# Getting specific JSON data into Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, json

I have an object of FX prices that I need to put into a data array for a chart.  The JSON looks like this.

```
    {date: "2020-02-10", open: 1.3301, high: 1.3329, low: 1.3285, close: 1.3317, …}
    {date: "2020-02-11", open: 1.3315, high: 1.332, low: 1.3272, close: 1.3287, …}
    {date: "2020-02-12", open: 1.3284, high: 1.3295, low: 1.3231, close: 1.325, …}
    {date: "2020-02-13", open: 1.3247, high: 1.327, low: 1.3236, close: 1.3268, …}
    {date: "2020-02-14", open: 1.3266, high: 1.3269, low: 1.3231, close: 1.3253, …}
    {date: "2020-02-16", open: 1.3248, high: 1.3255, low: 1.3237, close: 1.3237, …}
    {date: "2020-02-17", open: 1.3248, high: 1.3255, low: 1.3222, close: 1.3235, …}
```

I am looking for an elegant way to get just the close data into an array like this:
0: 1.3317
1: 1.3287
2: 1.325
3: 1.3268
4: 1.3253

Any suggestions?

Comment: Look at `Array.map()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: You don't specify if these objects are in an array... That is my assumption though

Comment: See this if it helps- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array

Comment: Assuming these objects are in 'data' array.
You can use - let closeArr = data.map(({close}) => close);

Comment: Thanks, map did the job nicely.